# Magento installation issues

Tags: magento, magento-rules

I developed a website using wordpress hosted with godaddy, I further wanted to include a magento solution with it by installing magento as a subfolder of the root. in the process of installing I get this errors.
Im not sure im doing it right

> Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\app\etc" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media\customer" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media\dhl" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media\dhl\logo.jpg" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media\downloadable" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media\xmlconnect" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media\xmlconnect\custom" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media\xmlconnect\custom\ok.gif" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media\xmlconnect\original" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media\xmlconnect\original\ok.gif" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media\xmlconnect\system" must be writable.
>   Path "D:\Hosting\11968835\html\magento\media\xmlconnect\system\ok.gif" must be writable.

Comment: Have you given right permissions to the magento directories and files?

Comment: @Muk, the files are readable, writable and executable

Answer (score 1):

this is a permissions issue.  I'm not a windows guy, but when I get this error, I run

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 pear
chmod 550 mage #for magento 1.5+
```

Then sometimes depending on the filesystem, I have to change the perms on Media and Var:

```
chmod -R 777 var  chmod-R 777 media
```

Obviously you don't want to leave 777 on there like that, but you can start there and work backwards.    Find the same folders on windows and change those perms and it'll solve your issue.